# XSL - Basically this: Return to the template that applied a template

Tags: xml, xpath

*Here is a description of my code-situation. The actual question might be reduced to the one you find in the title, details you find in the end of the post. But myabe I am searching in the wrong direction, so:*

this is a given structure, it's the content of an mysql table transformed to xml.

```
<result>
    <row>
        <col>..</col>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col>..</col>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col>..</col>
    </row>
    <row>
        <col>..</col>
    </row>
    [..]
</result>
```

Now I am trying to write an xsl file which has information about how to display these structure.

basically, it looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="//result">
    <table>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//result/row">
    <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//result/row/col">
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

and this works, but the difficulty for me now is to to make the depiction more variable, it should not always be "table", sometimes I need div's or any other html code to "render" each part of the table.

So I decided to mark this in another section of the xml file, like this:

```
<display>
    <MyTable>
        <MyRow>
            <MyCol/>
        </MyRow>
    </MyTable>
</display>
```

it could also look like this:

```
<display>
    <MyDiv>
        <MyDivSub>
            <MyDivSubSub/>
        </MyDivSub>
    </MyDiv>
</display>
```

However, these declarations are defined in the xsl file like this:

```
<xsl:template match="//display/MyTable">
    <table>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//display/MyTable/MyRow">
    <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//display/MyTable/MyRow/MyCol">
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

Now, My plan is to design the templates for result, row, col that they just call the templates which are specified in the display element of the xml file. This could even be like this:

```
<xsl:template match="//result">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//Display/*">
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//result/row">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//Display/*/*">
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//result/row/col">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//Display/*/*/*">
</xsl:template>
```

Of course at this point this is not working, because the applied templates are not going back to the result when they apply-templates inside of them. instead they apply them in the display section. This could be solved by the transmission of parameters. And I tried this, it works. But for me it is essential that the templates which containt the final depiction information (like MyTable, MyRow..) are not "messed up" with these extra lines. Later they could become quite complex anyways and there might be many of their kind so, I want to have their basic structure as minimal as possible. In other words: The magic function I am looking for would be this one, placed in the Depiction-Templates:

```
<xsl:template match="//display/MyTable">
    <table>
        <xsl:"GO BACK TO THE TEMPLATE THAT CALLED YOU"/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```

Is there a function like this, or does anybody know any other solution for my concern? Or do I have to accept the solution with the params? Which I cannot believe, because actually it is not such a complex procedure.

I hope I was clear, if any questions, ask. m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't think having one extra line in order to pass parameters is going to "mess them up". I don't think there's a way to do quite what you are describing, and even if there were, it wouldn't make sense. Wouldn't going back to the calling template just result in an infinite loop?

Is there something terribly problematic about the following? I think it's quite clean and flexible:

```
<xsl:template match="MyTable">
    <xsl:param name="context" select="/.." />
    <table>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$context/node()" />
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="MyRow">
    <xsl:param name="context" select="/.." />
    <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$context/node()" />
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="MyCol">
    <xsl:param name="context" select="/.." />
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="$context"/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="display" select="(//display)[1]" />

<xsl:template match="result">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$display/*">
        <xsl:with-param name="context" select="." />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="result/row">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$display/*/*">
        <xsl:with-param name="context" select="." />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="result/row/col">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$display/*/*/*">
        <xsl:with-param name="context" select="." />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thx! this worked. It was rather the way I used the params which annoyed me. I was not aware, that they can transmit a node.